# Saving data that was read from a file as a global variable HASKELL

Tags: haskell

I am creating a simple terminal game with Haskell and got stuck big time implementing health system. Ended up with idea to save changing health points to a text file, in this way keeping it as a "variable".

My code:

```
readHealth = do 
    theFile <- openFile "health.txt" ReadMode
    healthPoints <- hGetContents theFile
    return healthPoints
```

Problem here is that I can not access "healthPoints" outside of this readHealth thing... Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use global variables. This is a bit similar to "global state". `IO` means you define a *recipe* to obtain the value, it is not the value itself.

Comment: Just pass it as a variable, for example `GameContext` that contains data about the state of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an appropriate solution to your problem. It is impossible* to extract data from the `IO` monad, because that's not it's purpose. You should instead look into using the [`State`](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) monad family (or it's close cousins `StateT`), which lets you carry a mutable value along with you through the program, like so:

```
data Game = Game { health :: Int, ... }
type GameState = State Game
```

Then to read your value from the main thread, you use:

```
gameloop :: GameState ()
gameloop = do
    currentHealth <- gets health
    pure ()
```

To update the health, you need a short function:

```
updateHealth :: Int -> Game -> Game
updateHealth newHealth game = game { health = newHealth }
```

Then you can set health to 10 with:

```
gameloop :: GameState ()
gameloop = do
    modify $ updateHealth 10
    pure ()
```

Usage examples:

```
> evalState (gets health) (Game { health = 10 })
10

> evalState (modify (updateHealth 20) >> gets health) (Game { health = 10 })
20
```

* It is actually possible to extract values from `IO` using `unsafePerformIO`, but as the name suggests, it is unsafe to do so unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: You could also use Lenses, but I'll leave that for someone else to explain since I barely understand them myself. I think it's valuable to become familiar with basic States before diving into Lenses anyways.

Comment: Sorry again, have a missunderstanding on "currentHealth <- gets health" this part. If I use this block it just throws bunch of errors.

Comment: @HumanCode you should ask a new question and provide the exact code you're using. This code compiles, so it's probably just not interacting well with something else.